# How does a database update trigger a notification to application layer?

Tags: design, design-patterns, database-design, graph-databases

Application component 1(`ap1`) record/insert/update a new state in graph database(neo4j)

For every new state change in the database, application component 2(`ap2`) needs to be informed/notified that a new entry(event) is made. `ap2` would not like to poll database and track/find for state change.

[image]

---

`ap2` should not know the existence of `ap1`

Both application components will be written in GoLang

Database supports triggers & Stored procedures functionality. It is neo4j database.

OS Environment is Linux

I came across this article on notification: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/notifications.html

What is the design pattern to make `ap2` listen to any new event(immediately) on a database update? without `ap2` tracking & polling state changes in database

Comment: Please don't [cross post to multiple sites](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63863556/3404097). Please read about asking appropriate & good questions for a site. [ask]

Comment: @philipxy We are stuck with this design scenario... that we are looking to resolve. Question is very clear and precise. Instead of polling database for data changes, application layer needs notifications of those. Isn't this clear?

Comment: @philipxy I learnt that SE site  is more appropriate for such questions

Answer (score 2):

My first comment is that integrating through a database is an anti-pattern. You should strongly consider a different approach.

https://www.ben-morris.com/a-shared-database-is-still-an-anti-pattern-no-matter-what-the-justification/

That said, Domain Driven Development has the concept of Domain Events that you might want to look into
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation

It might be that the insert/update is not related to a domain event. Then you might want to consider to have the application doing the insert also trigger the event.

Comment: How can an application doing the insert also trigger event? Because we do not want `ap2` to know the existence of `ap1`.

Comment: I don't agree with Ben morris. Arista EOS is designed on same pattern. CA NSM is designed on same pattern.

Comment: “How can an application doing the insert also trigger event?” – `ap1` doesn't have to directly _trigger_ an event in `ap2`, it can _publish_ the event to a message broker (like RabbitMQ or Kafka). `ap2` can subscribe to this event in the broker. This way `ap1` and `ap2` don't know about each other, they only know about the broker.

Comment: @Archie if I use kafka, then why would I need database?

Comment: Because Kafka in not a database. Neither is RabbitMQ which I have also mentioned.